# Entity Framework and date+time arithmetic

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-5

We have the situation where we have a SQL Server 2005 table with a Date column and a separate Time column.  When I try to query this table, I'd like to do the equivalent of the following SQL:

`where Date + Time > @Something`

*Some background info - the Date is stored as a date with a 00:00 time component, and the Time is stored as a Time with a 1900-01-01 date component - this means in SQL adding the two together get you a full DateTime.*

I know there are indexing implications above, but that is not what the question is about.

**How do you do this in linq to entities?**

Some other things to note:

- Changing the database schema is out of the question.
- This is SQL 2005 so no Time datatype, and no TimeSpan returned from EF (I have tried changing the EF model to try and cast it to a TimeSpan, but no dice)
- I want to try and stick to pure Linq-to-Entities and not go down the E-SQL / stored procedure / ExecuteQuery route.

Answer (score 0):

Very lame idea, but:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-23");
var time = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 09:00:00);
var something = date + time;

[...] where Date + Time > something;
```

Comment: Within Linq to entities you can't do things like DateTime.Parse or add dates and dates together.  While possible, using separate calls like this isn't really what I'm looking for; I'd like a single linq to entities query to return the data.

Comment: Is is only one query. You just prepare the data you need beforehand. If that's not what you're looking for, I wonder why it is such a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework (versions > 4) has the EntityFunctions class.  So you can do something like:

```
... where EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 
             time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second) < DateTime.Now
```

Or you could just do it the old fashioned way:

```
... where date.Date < DateTime.Now.Date || (date.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && time.Time < DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the date.Year etc properties are not supported in a linq to entities query, and neither is .Date (in the second snippet).

Comment: @DavidHusselmann - that's the purpose of the EntityFunctions, it allows you to use them.